# How to display validation message if URL contains only .co

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

How to check if URL contain ".co" by using JavaScript regular expression

Comment: What do you mean "only .co" ?

Answer (score 0):

If the string you have only contains ".co" then just test

```
str.toLowerCase().trim() === ".co"
```

If you want to see if the URL is from .co, then this is a good way

```js
const url = new URL("https://www.aaa.co/page.html")
console.log(url.hostname // www.aaa.co
.split(".") //  ["www","aaa","co"]
.pop()  // co or CO or cO or Co
.toLowerCase() === "co")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex, it will find out if `.co` is used in the url.

```js
const rgxForCo = /\.co(\.|\b)/i;

const urls = ["www.gmail.co.uk", //true
  "www.ici.co", //true
  "www.google.com" //false
];

console.log(urls.map(url => rgxForCo.test(url)));
```